# What are Rein's capabilities with others?

Tags: nanoha

In *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha StrikerS*, Reinforce, like Agito, is referred to as a Unison Device, who can fuse with their master to increase their strength.

Rein is however a product of the Tome of the Night Sky and is referred to as a "control device" for the Tome of the Night Sky.

I am wondering, if Rein fuses with someone else, what is her capabilities? Does the person she fuses with have access to anything in the Tome of the Night Sky?

Answer (score 1):

The anime does not make this clear; fusing with a unison device simply increases the mage's offensive and defensive powers, and provides other effects, such as setting Signum's sword on fire when she unisoned with Agito.

While originally Hayate and Reinforce Zwei both used the Book of the Night Sky, later Reinforce got her own storage device - the Book of the Azure Sky.

(To provide a more specific answer would be to engage in speculation.)